# Failing Regex string thats correct

Tags: regex, vb.net

Hi this regex is driving me crazy in vb.NET:

It works on online regex testers but not in vb.NET:

```
Dim pattern1 As String="Version:</b>\s*<span>(.*)\<"
```

Doubling the backslashes `\\` didn't work, nor preceding the string with **@** as literal like c#
I also tried:

```
Dim pattern2 As String="<b\>Version:\</b\>+.*<span>(.*)</span>"
```

From this line, i must capture Beta:

```
<b>Version:</b>             <span> Beta </span>
```

Comment: what exactly is the error? what is the output that you get?

Comment: I finally found to post code here with ctrl k but youre fast less than 5 min and you corrected my post

Comment: I tested both of your patterns against the line you're trying to match, and got the following results: `Version:</b>             <span> Beta <` and `<b>Version:</b>             <span> Beta </span>`.  Perhaps you mean you're not getting just `Beta` back?

Comment: Can you post the code for where you're doing the matching?

Comment: One doesnt give any output, and the other one outputs the desired output and the regex

Comment: Yes Tim, i only want to extract Beta

Comment: `Dim colecversions As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(url, versionregex)`

Comment: Is `url` the same line as you posted in your question, or is it a complete HTML document?

Comment: url is a string that contains a 40 kb html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the problem.  [The regex works in the Regex Hero online tester](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=58c8c8f2-f8e3-449a-a44c-ef3a1d1a1e98) (including the capture group capturing `"Beta"`)...

[image: VB.NET Regex in Regex Hero Online]

...and works in the following VB.NET snippet it generated (to which I added a `Console.WriteLine` call for clarity):

```
Dim strRegex as String = "Version:</b>\s*<span>(.*)\<"
Dim myRegex As New Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None)
Dim strTargetString As String = "<b>Version:</b>             <span> Beta </span>"

For Each myMatch As Match In myRegex.Matches(strTargetString)
    If myMatch.Success Then
        Console.WriteLine(myMatch.Groups(1).Value)
    End If
Next
```

The snippet outputs what you want:

> Beta

Comment: `     Dim strRegex As String = "Version:</b>\s*<span>(.*)\<"
        Dim myRegex As New Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None)
        Dim strTargetString As String = "<b>Version:</b>             <span> Beta </span>"

        For Each myMatch As Match In myRegex.Matches(strTargetString)
            If myMatch.Success Then
                Console.WriteLine("Yup!")
                MessageBox.Show("Look at this output: " + myMatch.ToString)


            End If
        Next`

Comment: Joegan that code doesnt work for my vs studio, because i do a match.tostring and it doesnt print only beta, by the way how to paste multiline code here ? not with ` code `

Comment: I see you edited Joe3gan, Now Yes with the Groups(1).Value.ToString i needed works, THANKs

Comment: @user3470815: I ran the code in your comments and think I see the source of your confusion.  You don't need to output the match, you need to output the second element in the matches groups collection (the first element being the whole match, the second being the first match for the first capture group (i.e. `Beta`)) - per my update to the code snippet that Regex Hero generated.

Comment: @user3470815: You can't post multi-line code in comments to my knowledge.